# How to pass <option> in a <select> list into function whilst keeping track of selected options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
var items = [{
    name: 'someName',
    description: 'someDescription'
},
{
    name: 'someOtherName',
    description: 'someOtherDescription'
}];
```

And I want to **present them in a select box**, **track which objects are selected** as well as **allow the user to double click on an item and pass the item to a function** - so I can try do this:

```
<select multiple="true"
 ng-model="myModel"
 ng-options="item.name + ' ' + item.description for item in items"
 ng-dblclick="testFunction(item)">
</select>
```

My `testFunction` looks like this (in reality it's doing a little bit more than just dumping the item, but we can ignore that for the purpose of the question):

```
function testFunction(item) {
    console.log(item);
};
```

The list displays fine, however when the logging line in my `testFunction()` is executed, it is just printing undefined. `myModel` does keep track of which objects are selected.

I then tried a slightly different approach. I tried to populate the `<option>` list using ng-repeat:

```
<select multiple="true" ng-model="myModel">
    <option ng-repeat item in items" ng-dblclick="testFunction(item)">
        {{item.name}} - {{item.description}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now this almost gets me over the line. My `testFunction()` now receives the object fine. However, now my `myModel` is only populating with strings of whatever is in the text part of the `<option>` tag.

It seems like I am unable to get both of these things happening at once.

Is anyone able to help? Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select multiple="true" ng-model="myModel">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-dblclick="testFunction(item)"value="{{item}}">
        {{item.name}} - {{item.description}}
    </option>
</select>
```

You need to be setting the value attribute on the options element to the item object. otherwise it will default to whatever is being displayed.

Comment: I thought that was going to be it, but when setting `value="item"`, `myModel` is always set to `"item"`

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry it's value="{{item}}" otherwise, it's just setting it to the string item :P

Comment: Yeah I had that same brain lapse, haha. The problem I'm facing now is that setting `value="{{item}}"` is causing `myModel` to contain a stringified version of the object (i.e. it will look something like this: `["{\"name\":\"111\",\"description\":\"222\"` - is there any way to get it to store an object, rather than a string?

Comment: I saw the plunker you posted (appreciated). I just slightly modified it so you can see the problem I'm having. http://plnkr.co/edit/LGRLWFAQfYaa8nVOCme2?p=preview as you can see it's saving the stringified version of the object into `myModel` - is there a way to save it as an object?

Comment: This is a bit of a simplified version of my actual code. Basically there is a form I'm working with that has some pretty complex logic. However, one requirement that I can't really avoid addressing is that this particular list needs to be able to have multiple items selected at any time, as well as the ability to double click on a single item and edit it's "properties" (simple key-value properties) in a modal popup. In addition to this, items can be moved between lists but I've already got that worked out so isn't a problem :) Thanks so much for your help!